# `ProvisionException` is cached and constructor code is never retried

Tags: java, playframework, guice

I have a Java web service built using PlayFramework 2.6.5 and Guice DI (`libraryDependencies += guice`), just in time injection mode. All dependencies are injected via constructor, using `@Inject` and `@ImplementedBy`, and the Guice `Module` is empty.

Due to transient errors, some dependencies can throw an exception in the constructor. When this happens the service fails with a `ProvisionException` (which is ok, clients are expected to retry).

I found that these exceptions are cached, and even when the root cause of the exception is solved, either Play or Guice never retry instantiating these classes, and keep trowing the same exception until the web service is restarted.

Consider for example the following class `Clock` with a constructor that fails if it's midnight (00:xx). As soon as the system clock reaches midnight, the service fails to instantiate the class. When clock reaches 1am, the same exception keeps being thrown. Also, the exception message is always the same (in the example the exception message is the time of the first time an exception occurred)

```
@ImplementedBy(OddClock.class)
public interface IClock {
    //...
}

public class OddClock implements IClock {
    @Inject
    public OddClock() throws Exception {
        if (DateTime.now().hourOfDay().get() == 0) {
            throw new Exception(DateTime.now().toString());
        }
    }
}

public class TimeController {
    @Inject
    public TimeController(IClock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }
}
```

btw, the same codebase is used also in a console application, which doesn't suffer from this issue, so I'm thinking there's something special in Play+Guice integration. Any suggestion to turn off the exception caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to make PF's behavior more explicit and predictable. The Routes generated by PF by default caches controllers even when their instances are broken, assuming singleton controllers are what a user wants.

As described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection), the default behavior can be changed adding a `@` in front of each action in the routes configuration.

e.g., before:

```
GET    /test    webservice.TestController.test
```

after:

```
GET    /test    @webservice.TestController.test
```

With this syntax, controllers are not singleton-by-default, and one can still use `@Singleton` where needed. Also, singleton controllers are not cached in case of exceptions, allowing transient errors to recover without restarting the service.
A copy of the code is available [here](https://github.com/dluc/SO-47106044-playframework).

Answer (score 1):

Throwing exceptions and caching the exceptions seems like a built-in behaviour in Guice. It's a fair behaviour too, since Guice expects objects that it creates to avoid IO and other non-deterministic actions.

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BeCarefulAboutIoInProviders

> Provider doesn't define a retry-strategy. When a value is unavailable, calling get() multiple times may cause multiple failed provisions.

You may be able to avoid the caching by changing the *scope* that you use so that the instance is recreated each time. E.g. using transient scoping instead of singletons.

A better solution, in my opinion, would be to get your unreliable object and wrap it in another object that hides failures and handles retries. That way Guice would always succeed when it tries to create the reliable object and you could add your own failure handling code inside the reliable wrapper.

E.g. a simple example that retries construction:

```
public class ReliableClock { 
  private Factory<Clock> clockFactory;
  private Clock internalClock;
  public ReliableClock(Factory<Clock> clockFactory) {
    this.clockFactory = clockFactory;
  }
  private synchronized Clock currentClock() throws Exception {
    if (clock == null) {
      clock = clockFactory.create() // May throw exception
    }
    return clock;
  }
  // ... methods ...
}
```

Comment: This would work.  I can't help feeling that it would be tidier to redesign the `IClock` implementation to simply avoid throwing exceptions in the constructor though.  Couldn't that validation be done lazily?

Comment: I agree that if it's possible to resolve the exceptions at the root cause then that would be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and I agree that ideally the code could be improved, but unfortunately that's not the case in the real scenario (the one above is a very simple example to illustrate the problem).  

    @RichDougherty: _Throwing exceptions and caching the exceptions seems like a built-in behaviour in Guice._

I still don't understand why the issue affects only the web service and not the console application (see my last sentence) though, both are using Guice.  Are Play Framework controllers instantiated as singletons?

Comment: @DevisLucato, it's hard to say why the code is different in Play vs your console application. It could be a difference in how Guice is being used or a difference in the environment that means exceptions don't occur in the first place. Probably requires more information/debugging to understand why.

"Are Play Framework controllers instantiated as singletons?"

By default I believe they're transient (the Guice default), unless you use the `@Singleton` annotation.